# Animate div from right to left and then from left to right again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I try to animate a div from its original position to left of the screen, if a button was clicked. If another button is clicked then i want it to animate back to it's origin position. I was able to figure out on how to animate it from right to left, but i cant animate it back to its original position.

```js
var left = $('#coolDiv').offset().left;

$("#b1").click(
  function() {
    $("#coolDiv").css({
      left: left
    }).animate({
      "left": "0px"
    }, "slow");
  }
);

$("#b2").click(
  function() {
    $("#coolDiv").css({
      right: right
    }).animate({
      "right": "0px"
    }, "slow");
  }
);
```

```css
#coolDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
#b1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coolDiv">cool</div>
<button id="b1">left</button>
<button id="b2">right</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/5385/

Comment: My advice, is to delegate the "transition" stuff to CSS, and the click logic to JS.

Comment: Check my answer and the fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `left` CSS to the window width minus the width of the box.

```js
$("#b1").click(function() {
  // Get the current left of the div
  var left = $('#coolDiv').offset().left;

  $("#coolDiv").css({
    left: left
  }).animate({
    left: 0
  }, "slow");
});

$("#b2").click(function() {
  var left = $(window).width() - $('#coolDiv').width();

  $("#coolDiv").css({
    left: 0
  }).animate({
    left: left
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
#coolDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
#b1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coolDiv">cool</div>
<button id="b1">Left</button>
<button id="b2">Right</button>
```

---

**Optimized Code:**

```js
// Common function to animate Div on both button clicks
function animateDiv(left, right) {
  $('#coolDiv').css({
    left: left
  }).stop(true, true).animate({
    left: right
  }, 'slow');
}

$('#b1').click(function() {
  animateDiv($('#coolDiv').offset().left, 0);
});

$('#b2').click(function() {
  animateDiv(0, $(window).width() - $('#coolDiv').width());
});
```

```css
#coolDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
#b1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coolDiv">cool</div>
<button id="b1">Left</button>
<button id="b2">Right</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something simple like this?

```js
$(function () {
  $(".animateable").animate({
    left: $(window).innerWidth() - 50
  }, 1000, function () {
    $(".animateable").animate({
      left: 0
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI; line-height: 1;}
.animateable {position: absolute; width: 50px; text-align: center; background-color: #ccf; line-height: 2em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div class="animateable">
  Hi
</div>
```

You can use `setInterval` to make it work a lot of times.

```js
$(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    $(".animateable").animate({
      left: $(window).innerWidth() - 50
    }, 1000, function () {
      $(".animateable").animate({
        left: 0
      }, 1000);
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI; line-height: 1;}
.animateable {position: absolute; width: 50px; text-align: center; background-color: #ccf; line-height: 2em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div class="animateable">
  Hi
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your updated code. Make changes like following:

```js
$("#b1").click(
  function() {
    $("#coolDiv").animate({
        "left": "0px"
      },
      "slow"
    );
    $("#coolDiv").css('right', '');
  }
);

$("#b2").click(
  function() {

    $("#coolDiv").animate({
        "right": "0px"
      },
      "slow"
    );
    $("#coolDiv").css('left', '');
  }
);
```

```css
#coolDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
#b1 {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coolDiv">cool</div>
<button id="b1">B1</button>
<button id="b2">B2</button>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Note that this answer doesn't animate the Div, also try to click on the button multiple times.

Comment: But the div is moving, isn't it?